# i want to return the projects of specific user?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to return the projects of the authenticated user, but am not getting any. I know the records exist in the database.

This is my model `Project`:

```
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

this is my model `User`:

```
public function projects(){
    return $this->hasMany(Projet::class,'user_id');
}
```

and this is the controller function :

```
public function projetuser(){
   $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
   return $user->projects;
}
```

and this my `user_projet` migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_projet', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('projet_id');
        $table->foreign('projet_id')->references('id')->on('projets')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->string('membre')->nullbale();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: And do you have any error ? You can just use : `$user = auth()->user();`

Comment: the probelm is can't get the projects of the user authenticated he return to me an empty array

Comment: Can you add the user and project migrations to your question and does the user actually have any projects in the database?

Comment: Are there any project in your db?

Comment: i have edited my post @Remul

Comment: You can read more about many-to-many relationships [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). Could you try changing `hasMany` to `belongsToMany `

Comment: a bit offtopic, can a project be own only by a user? if yes, you don't even need a pivot table...

Comment: no @ GiuServ   i mean the user can have many project (i try to build a managment project )   => the user can be a developer or designer who can participate in many projects

Comment: $userprojetid=userprojet::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->first();
        return Projet::where('id',$userprojetid->projet_id)->get();
i have try this solution but he show me one project 
and in the DB the user authenticated have 2 projects??

Comment: `auth()->user()->projects` will work, you just have to fix your relationships.

Comment: i know but the problem in the relationships??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) incorrectly. Use `belongsToMany()` instead of `hasMany()`. Because your pivot table name is not standard (it should be alphabetic order `projet_user`) you need to include it in the relationship definition as well.

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Projet extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_projet');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    public function projets(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Projet::class, 'user_projet');
    }
}
```

Now in your controller you can do this:

```php
public function projetuser(){
    return auth()->user->projets;
}
```

Your question seems to vary between "projet" and "project." I assumed "projet" was the correct spelling, but try to keep this consistent.

Please note also the typo in your migration: `nullbale`.